# How do I locate a record in an SQL query in MS Access VBA using FindFirst?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am building a process to store a list of parts to a set of locations. One thing I want to do is keep the database from associating the same part number more than once in a location. I have a database set up, and everything should work. However, I get an error at the FindFirst function saying "Invalid Argument". Everything looks like it should be ok according to Microsoft's documentation, so I am stumped on how to fix this problem.

Here's the portion of the code that is part of it:

```
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim rstDup As Recordset
    Dim partNumber As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim Location As String
    Location = Forms!frmCheckIn!cboLocation
    strSQL = "SELECT PartNumber FROM tblWarehouse WHERE tblWarehouse.Location='" + Location + "';"
    
    Set db = Nothing
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rstDup = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    partNumber = tbxPartNumber
    
    'Need to add protection against duplicate part number in location.
    rstDup.MoveFirst
    rstDup.MoveLast
    rstDup.MoveFirst
    rstDup.FindFirst "partNumber"
    If rstDup.NoMatch = False Then
        MsgBox ("Part number is already in location. Place parts in location or select a new location.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: in strsql replace both + with & then remove the ; at the end.  In vba & is the string concatenating operator and in vba the sql is not terminated with a  ;  yes in the query designer it is terminated with a ;  Maybe that is all you need.

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicate combinations of PartNumber and Location, consider creating an index on those 2 columns and assigning the unique property.

Comment: Changed those and still am getting the same error. It's not strSQL that's the issue, since it gets run in opening up the Recordset and the locals window is showing the correct results from the query at that point in the process.

Comment: True, semi-colon is not needed but won't hurt. The '+' character will concatenate text but will behave differently from '&' concatenation if one input is Null. What part number do you want to find? `rstDup.FindFirst "partNumber = '" & Me.tbxPartNumber & "'"`. But you don't even need to use FindFirst. Open recordset with Location and PartNumber filter criteria then check if the recordset is empty. Or instead of opening recordset, use DLookup().

Comment: Could also design a combobox that will only offer part numbers that aren't already in the specified location.

Comment: In regards to setting both Location and PartNumber as unique: I want there to be the same part number multiple times in the database, but I don't want it to associate with the same location more than once. So if part 12345 is already in Aisle 1, I don't want the user to be able to add it again. But the table this information is getting accessed from is more of a transaction history that gets added to and subtracted from.

Comment: HansUp suggested you set the combination of Location and PartNumber as a unique compound index. This will prevent duplicate pairs and Access will nag user when attempting to save record. However, I prefer to catch possible duplication before the point of saving record, as your code attempts. Did you see my previous comments?

Comment: The `rstDup.FindFirst "partNumber = '" & Me.tbxPartNumber & "'"` worked. I didn't want to use a combobox because there are way too many part numbers to populate and I'm having trouble forming the DLookup function to check what I need it to.

Comment: Why do you feel there are too many part numbers? I have combobox with thousands of items listed. Might find this of interest http://allenbrowne.com/ser-32.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FindFirst is not provided any parameter to search for. What part number do you want to find?
`rstDup.FindFirst "partNumber = '" & Me.tbxPartNumber & "'"`

But you don't even need to use FindFirst. Open recordset with Location and PartNumber filter criteria then check if recordset is empty.
`If Not rstDup.EOF Then`

Or instead of opening recordset, use DLookup(). Most of that procedure code could be replaced with:
`If Not IsNull(DLookup("PartNumber", "tblWarehouse", "Location='" & Me.cboLocation & "'")) Then`

Comment: I had to add `= False` to the end of the DLookup statement so that it would exit the subroutine if it did find a matching part number. Thank you for the solutions!

Comment: Right, I edited answer to use `If Not` - works same as `= False`.